# How to push to the original remote repository after rewriting with git-filter-repo

Tags: git, git-remote, git-filter-repo

I removed a sensitive string from all the repo history, using [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo).

Now, in my local git, I see

1. I don't have the `remote` anymore.
2. All the commits are with tag about the old commit (`replace/deb3de48620ffc7a9f9f0210a3111da398d67c57`)
3. After adding the remote back, all local branches are on different commits from the `origin` branches.

How can I remove the `replace/` tags and push the whole git history to replace the history in the `remote`?

Comment: `git-filter-repo`, just like `git-filter-branch` - rewrites the history. All your commit ids have been changed. Your old commits are useless (as you wanted to change them anyway). You could delete your remote and create a new git remote. Then push these changes to the new git repo

Comment: @clmno I know, but I have integrations in the remote (on Github), so I want to push all the changes to the same remote. If I will create a new one, or delete the Github repo and recreate it, I will have to reconfigure the CI/CD systems and all.

Comment: You could `git push --force`. Note: I've never done a `git-filter-repo`. But technically your local and remote have a few commits in common and so when you do a `--force` you're asking remote to be updated with what's in the local. Just like how you do a `--force` after a `git amend`. Again, all this is "technically"

Comment: Yes, this is part of the answer. I did `git push --mirror`. But I still have the tags on each commit.

Comment: Tags on the old commits. Tags are associated with commit ids. So you might have to manually "re-tag"